# php shell_exec fails when return non-ascii string

Tags: php, python, exec, ascii, globalization

using command

```
$ret = shell_exec($command);
```

results in `$ret` being null when `$command` returns string containing non-ascii characters (papír), but it works when `$command` returns string without non-ascii characters

same happens when using exec or system

as `$command` i tried

```
'LANG=en_US.utf-8; python myapp.py '.escapeshellarg($in);
'python myapp.py '.escapeshellarg($in);
```

results obviously depends on $in, but it works when `$in` contains non-ascii characters and script returns only ascii characters, so problem is with output not input in my opinion

Comment: i creat a file command: `#!/bin/bash          
STR="papír"
echo $STR` then i run php -r "var_dump(shell_exec('./command 2>&1'));" which doesn't retrun null but (string(7) "papír
"). NOTE `php -r "echo strlen( 'papír' );"` will give 6 (the number of bytes).

Comment: all this works for me. After using it to test i found that myapp.py also fails when redirected to file. `myapp.py > out.txt` results in UnicodeEncodeError.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224268/python-unicode-encode-error

Comment: i fixed it with adding `export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8;` before command