# Selenium webdriver and unicode

Tags: python, selenium, unicode

It's my 2nd day with Selenium 2 library and the pain with Unicode never seem to subside.

I'm just doing the most basic operation, want to print the page source:

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://google.com")

print driver.page_source
```

Sure enough, I get an error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0119' in position 62045:  
ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I please encode this to `utf-8` ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have options, based on this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224268/python-unicode-encode-error).

You can either convert the source to all ascii losing the Unicode characters in the process.

`(driver.page_source).encode('ascii', 'ignore')`

Or, and I think you'll prefer this, you can encode it to utf-8 like this:
`(driver.page_source).encode('utf-8')`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `print(string)`, use `print(repr(string))` [to return a printable representation of the object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr).