# Selenium webdriver and URIError: "String contained an illegal UTF-16 sequence"

Tags: html, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-3.5

**Background:** I just learned how to use "Webdriver" and "Beautifulsoup" for two days.

**Problem:**
I use the following code to download a webpage:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path)
driver.get('https://mojim.com/twy100468x17x18.htm')
pageSource = driver.page_source
...
```

then, I encountered this error

```
WebDriverException: Message: URIError - String contained an illegal UTF-16 sequence.
```

**Try:** I try to replace `pageSource = browser.page_source` with
`(driver.page_source).encode('ascii', 'ignore')`
  `(driver.page_source).encode('utf-8')` 
(suggested by [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823086/selenium-webdriver-and-unicode))
but still end in with the same error....

**Page Source**
[here](https://mojim.com/twy100468x17x18.htm)

What should I do? Is there an illegal text in the html or what?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive just overcome this situation. This is caused by different non UTF chars
[image]

I solved this surprisingly with Edge driver (Chrome and Mozilla doesnt handle that). So you can use it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get('https://mojim.com/twy100468x17x18.htm')
pageSource = driver.page_source
```

The thing is that Edge is not headless like PhantomJS so when scraping i use it only on this bad excepted links. Also Egde is almost as fast as PhantomJS.