# json encoded as UTF-8 characters. How do I process as json in Python Requests

Tags: python, json, http, request

I am scraping a website that is rendering a JavaScript/JSON Object that looks like this:

```
{ "company": "\r\n            \x3cdiv class=\"page-heading\"\x3e\x3ch1\x3eSEARCH
 RESULTS 1 - 40 OF 200\x3c/h1\x3e\x3c/div\x3e\r\n\r\n             
\x3cdiv class=\"right-content-list\"\x3e\r\n\r\n                
\x3cdiv class=\"top-buttons-adm-lft\"\x3e\r\n
```

I am attempting to process this as a JSON Object (which is what this looks like) using Python's Requests library.

I have used the following methods to encode/process the text:

```
unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", get_city_json.text).encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", get_city_json.text).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
unicode(get_city_json.text)
```

However, even after repeated attempts, the text is rendered with the UTF-8 encoding and its characters. 
The Content-Type returned by the web app is `"text/javascript; charset=utf-8"`

I want to be able to process it as a regular JSON/JavaScript Object for parsing and reading.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

That isn't `UTF-8`. It HTML encoded text.

You can decode it using the following:

### Python 2

```
import HTMLParser
html_parser = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
unescaped = html_parser.unescape(json_value)
print unescaped
```

### Python 3

```
import html.parser    
html_parser = html.parser.HTMLParser()
unescaped = html_parser.unescape(json_value)
print unescaped
```

If you unescape your string with these you should get

```
<div class="page-heading"><h1>SEARCH RESULTS 1 - 40 OF 200</h1></div>
<div class="right-content-list">
<div class="top-buttons-adm-lft">
```

Comment: This isnt working for me. I am getting an error like so..

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xbb' in position 33759: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: This isn't related to the code I gave you. You need to remove the `normalize`/`encode` functions you posted in your question.

Comment: No, I have removed those functions. I am attempting to process this directly. The error was thrown when attempting to print `unescaped`

Comment: I see. Some machines with older Python versions have this problem. There are workarounds here for the `print` problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224268/python-unicode-encode-error

Comment: I am able to print it now, but the HTMLParser doesnt seem to be unescaping anything. Same representation