# RFID reader connection error with raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, rfid

We are trying to read RFID tags using raspberry pi b+. We used following script in the python .

```
import serial
import time
serial=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", baudrate=2400)
while True:
    if serial.inWaiting()>0:
        read_result=serial.read(12)
        print("Read card {0}",format(read_result.decode("utf-8","replace")))
        print("Sleeping 2 sec")
        time.sleep(2)
        serial.flushInput()
```

On reading the tag it gives the error as:

```
File "/home/pi/rfidtry/try.py",line 7, in <module>
print("Read card {0}",format(read_result.decode("utf-8","replace")))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codac can't encode character u'\uffd' in position 2
:ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Can you omit the `replace` and show the output? (It should give you a slightly different error message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the baudrate.
The earlier reader i used was 2400
but the one i am using now is 9600.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224268/python-unicode-encode-error), it might work if you encoded your unicode string first to ascii and then decode it.

```
read_result.encode('ascii','replace').decode('utf-8')
```

Of course, you will lose the non-working characters.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this

```
print read_result
```

and see if it works (instead of )

```
print("Read card {0}",format(read_result.decode("utf-8","replace")))
```

Comment: This should most likely have been a comment.