# pandas dataframe and u'\u2019'

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, unicode, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe (python 2.7) containing a u'\u2019' that does not let me extract as csv my result.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 180: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there a way to query the dataframe and substitude these character with another one?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224268/python-unicode-encode-error and map the proper column with such encoding function

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: See my answer (simpler solution)

Answer (score 1):

Try using a different encoding when saving to file (the default in pandas for Python 2.x is ascii, that's why you get the error since it can't handle unicode characters):

```
df.to_csv(path, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: I tried but it does not work. I get: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 131152: invalid start byte

Comment: Could you somehow provide us of the dataframe data? it's clear there are strange characters in your dataset which makes writing to file fail.

Comment: It is confidential data that I cannot share.

Answer (score 0):

I did not manage to export the whole file. However, I managed to identity the row with the character causing problems and eliminate it

```
faulty_rows = []
for i in range(len(outcome)):
    try:
        test = outcome.iloc[i]
        test.to_csv("/Users/john/test/test.csv")
    except:
        pass
        faulty_rows.append(i)
        print i


tocsv = tocsv.drop(outcome.index[[indexes]])    

tocsv.to_csv("/Users/john/test/test.csv")
```