# convert ascii characters in python

Tags: python, salesforce

I am trying to pull data from salesforce however facing some issues while reading ascii characters.For example
Original value in salesforce db

```
 6 articles, plus 2 pieces of content labeled “expert answers”
```

Value i get in python

```
 6 articles, plus 2 pieces of content labeled \u201cexpert answers\u201d
```

Seems like double quotes are converted to ascii.When i try to wrap above string in python str() method it throws below error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in position 45: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there any way i can convert this ascii to original value to save it in my db?

Comment: that's actually called "unicode", not ascii.

Comment: ohh sorry, my bad!!but is there any way to convert this back to original characters?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224268/python-unicode-encode-error