# PyInstaller codecs issues

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Working on Ubuntu 16.04, python 2.7.12, I have this code (codec.py):

```
#!usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import codecs

text = u'pi: \u03c0'
print text
```

Start program with: python codec.py work fine, and display:

```
pi: π
```

After compile this code with pyinstaller 3.3 I try to execute program with ./codec, but receive this error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "codec.py", line 7, in <module>
   UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u03c0' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
   [6816] Failed to execute script codec
```

I have no solution for that issue. Have you ?

Solution was to modify line 7:

print text.encode("utf-8")

After compile with pyinstaller, program work fine, without error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using IDLE 3 instead of 2.7?
I find a lot of the issues stem from using the wrong python versions due to library incompatibility.

Also take a look at : [Python Unicode Encode Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224268/python-unicode-encode-error)

Maybe your syntax is incorrect?

Comment: Program work fine when is started with python codec.py. Problem is with the compiled program.

Comment: oh okay try setting the encoding to a default value.
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

Comment: Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding'
>>>

Comment: Solution come from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828723/why-should-we-not-use-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8-in-a-py-script , second answer: print text.encode("utf-8") . After this modify I compile again and program run fine now. Thank Harvey, looking for sys.setdefaultencoding, I find this answer.