# Python3 UnicodeEncodingError

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 
r'C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://www.imdb.com/')

html_doc = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())

driver.quit()
```

i tried this code and it gives this error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Practice\WebScraping\webscrape.py", line 11, in 
print(soup.prettify())
File "C:\Users\vmbck\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25ec' in position 241524: character maps to

then i tried with encode("utf-8")

```
html_doc = driver.page_source.encode("utf-8")
```

again it gives that error

how can i get page_source without getting UnicodeEncodeError

Comment: thank you very much.... i fixed that with html_doc = ascii(driver.page_source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
a = requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(a.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())
```

The above code does similar to what you have written. But, to solve the unicode error, you can try doing what was suggested in the following post 
[Python Unicode Encode Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224268/python-unicode-encode-error)

Answer (score -1):

if encoding to utf-8 is failing try to encode to ascii

try both : -

```
print(soup.encode('utf-8').prettify())
```

and

```
print(soup.encode('ascii').prettify())
```

Comment: found this too...The problem is that the console you're running on is not capable of handling the character you're trying to print: … See stackoverflow.com/questions/3597480/… for some hints.

Comment: Ascii is a (very small) subset of UTF-8 so the best that the using ASCII encoding can do is nothing. However it will guarantee corruption of Unicode characters with a code point of above 127.